# prepositional phrases used as nouns

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Looking for examples of prepositional phrases that function as nouns. This example has been given:

'After three o'clock would be more convenient for me.' 'After three o'clock' serves as the subject.

Is the prepositional phrase in the sentence below another example of use as a noun?

'I forgot about eating dinner because I was so distraught.'

Is it correct to say that 'about eating dinner' serves as the direct object?

Comment: No, 'about eating dinner' is not a self-contained expression. The verb is 'to forget about X'.  The phrase 'eating dinner' is the object and is a gerund followed by a noun.

Comment: Oh, thank you. 'Forget about' is a phrasal verb, then? Are there any instances of prepositional phrases used as direct objects?

Comment: _In the bedroom is not where we usually find these things._ Most prepositions are used to mark noun phrases in one way or another, and they  can certainly be subjects or objects, for instance.

Comment: I don't think a preposition can function as a noun. The example you gave can be interpreted as an ellipsis that's omitting whatever noun the preposition modifies. 

"*Meeting* after three o'clock is more convenient for me."

Comment: In the second example, "about eating dinner" is an prepositional adverb phrase modifying forgot. There's no object in the sentence.